# Is this (not) an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37101150/861716) as not an answer.

Question:

> Is there a way to setup EF so that it recognizes the Parent/Child relationship so I can effectively have a subordinates collection?

"Answer":

> The problem with EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId that is not official by EntityFramework team currently, it is a fork

To me, this clearly is a comment on the answer already given, but, as so often, entered as an answer by a <50 rep user. But my flag was declined.

Did a mod press the wrong button? (After all, they're human beings). Or is there something I have to learn about NAA?

Comment: That is an answer that should not be flagged and was rightfully declined. See also [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). That doesn't mean it is correct or helpful. It just means the Very Low Quality review queue does not deal with posts like that (see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).

Comment: Looking at the post's [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37101150/timeline), it looks like it was flagged in the [late answer review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12282397) but something invalidated it from the [Low Quality Posts review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12282468) (presumably a mod).

Comment: @Tunaki I don't agree with that. The OP uses a not-supported library, so what? The comment doesn't point to another castle. A real answer should at least have shown an alternative, like: use another hierarchy implementation. That's the other castle.

Comment: The question is not whether it is a real answer or not. The "Not An Answer" flag is inappropriate for wrong or incorrect or misleading or poor answers. As a general rule, if you need to get to down to technical details, you shouldn't flag.

Comment: @Tunaki I know. And I don't think it is an answer at all. It's not an effort to solve OP's problem. That's the least an answer should do. I've left many many very bad answers unflagged because at least they tried.

Comment: To evaluate the answer, don't look at the question. Forget the question and decide based only on the answer if it is NAA-flag worthy or not. In this case, I do see an attempt: the OP is saying that using a fork is a problem. I agree it is poor and I also agree that the question wasn't asking that, _but_ there is some piece of information in there (mainly that you shouldn't use the fork but prefer the official version). I also agree that it _could_ have been a comment, and it _could_ have been converted to one. But all of this does not make it NAA.

Comment: ... It simply makes this a bad answer on which you are free to vote accordingly and use your delete votes if you want. But not involve the VLQ review queue and moderator flags.

Comment: @Tunaki Well, it's arbitrary at best. I see many answers like this in the LQ queue, sometimes I leave them exactly for what you say: there is some useful info in them. This one I would have agreed with.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes... but it's not because some users are doing it wrong that you should do the same ;) see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue

Comment: @Tunaki "To evaluate the answer, don't look at the question" that's entirely misguided. The whole "Your answer is on another castle" forces you to look at the context, and this has been argued before many times. That answer doesn't " fundamentally answer the question" neither "even a partial answer to the actual question". Is a comment. And now it has been deleted and [converted to a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363332/entity-framework-hierarchyid-workarounds/37101150#comment55482975_15729540).

Comment: @Braiam Reason for it to be deleted is not reason for it to be flagged.

Comment: @Tunaki well, it was converted to a comment, so a moderator believed that it wasn't an answer. It is a comment, is *not an answer*. And the deletion is just the most direct way to inform other users that such answers are not accepted. So, flagging was correct, and shouldn't have been declined.

Comment: @Braiam But it wasn't converted to a comment? It was just deleted by 3 20kers that used their delete votes. That's not the same comment you linked to. (I think you searched for "The problem with" and didn't look at the rest :p) --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/MNH9B.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's *not* an answer. It's a comment that provides no solution information whatsoever. The flag should have been accepted.

Answer (score -4):

Without knowing the subject matter, it looks like it might be just a poor attempt at an answer. But that would still make it an answer (technically), so it could be why the flag was declined. People make mistakes, you know.

See here for more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181026

From what you say, it's not really an answer. It's just not obvious at first glance.

In the future, I would suggest that you leave a comment saying *why* it doesn't answer the question, because that will be helpful to the reviewers that don't have experience in that area. (And it might help the flag get processed faster.)

Comment: *leave a comment saying why it doesn't answer the question* There you're right. I'm afraid a little bit of routine sneaked in. For the rest, I think it's very hard to make the distinction. I see so many pseudo answers from <50 users...

Comment: @gert As someone who was <50 very recently, the short comment is the *single most useful thing* that helps me get with the program. Without it I'm left in complete confusion as to what I'm doing wrong. Doesn't need to be long, just point me in the general direction of my inadequacies. It's the biggest barrier to entry here I think - the mysterious unexplained downvote .

Comment: @user6170930 Keep in mind that my account's almost as new. I've been around 20 days longer than you. There are some things that deserve down votes without comment (like spam/trolling/etc) but if a user seems to be willing to work, I try to help them improve.

Comment: @Laurel That's almost twice as long ;)  but I'm content with +500 in a month. Never feed the trolls of course. It was things like  "-1 because the question I answered was low quality" that caused me confusion. A comment would really have helped there, instead it took a meta post to figure that out.